# How to turn a listbox.selecteditems into a variable with additional text

Tags: powershell, variables, listboxitem

I am building a vocabulary trainer with a GUI and am stuck with a Listbox.
The Listbox has several topics to choose from and it works as requested.

Now I am struggling, to combine/merge the listbox.selecteditems, to add some text to it and put it into a variable

I tried to merge it by using the following code:

```
$TopicAnswer = '$listBox.SelectedItems_Answer'



[void] $ListBox.Items.Add('Weekdays')
[void] $ListBox.Items.Add('Months')
[void] $ListBox.Items.Add('Numbers 1-10')
[void] $ListBox.Items.Add('Numbers 10-20')
```

So the idea is, that when I for example choose 'Weekdays', I would like to have a variable that will become 'Weekdays_Answer'

I have tried several ways but usually end up with the content:

```
$listBox.SelectedItems_Answer
```

instead of

```
Weekdays_Answer
```

The idea behind it is, that I have pairs of arrays, where I have a topic name together with the topic name answer. So as soon as I have chosen a topic, I want a new variable that has this specific name and ads the underscore Answer to it, so I have the pairing arrays together for my vocabulary training.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help and support,

Mike

Comment: Try $TopicAnswer = $listbox_selecteditems.text + "_Answer"

Comment: Hello Scepticalist,
Thank you for your suggestion but it didn't work unfortunately.
I got closer with using this: 

$listbox.selecteditems)+'_Answer'

But here I get the weekdays and _Answer on two lines

Answer (score 0):

Thanx to you, I was able to figure it out.

```
$TopicAnswer = $listbox.text+'_Answer'
```

It works on this way. Thank you very much for your hint. You might did a typo but it helped to solve the issue.

Thanx,

Mike